# Mixed-effects model when the response has two distinct distributions for two levels of an explanatory factor

Tags: mixed-model, gamma-distribution, lognormal-distribution, brms

I have a continuous response variable called "distance," which was measured in two different years (2019, 2020), and each year exhibited a significantly different distribution. In 2019, the best-fitted distribution was "log-normal," while in 2020, it was a "gamma" distribution. To analyze the data, I utilized the "brms" extension by Paul Bürkner and created two separate models, one for each year, due to the distinct distributions.

The simplified definitions of the final models are as follows:

For 2019:

```r
mymodel.2019 <- brm(distance | cens(censored) ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + 
                       (1 | stationID), data = mydata2019, 
                       family = "lognormal", ...)
```

For 2020:

```r
mymodel.2020 <- brm(distance | cens(censored) ~ v1 + v5 + v6 + v4 + 
                       (1 | tree/g.stationID/stationID), 
                       data = mydata2020, family = "gamma", ...)
```

I arrived at the final model for each year using a backward step-wise approach from the same initial set of variables. However, even though the "full models" had the same explanatory variables, the final models ended up with different variables. Additionally, the random structure of the best-fit models was also different for the two years.

Ideally, I would have preferred to create a single model with the "year" variable included as a factor-type explanatory variable with two levels (2019 and 2020). However, the two years appeared to be distinct in terms of their distributions, prompting me to opt for the two separate models. After submitting the paper, I received feedback from a reviewer who suggests incorporating the "year" variable as an explanatory variable instead of running two separate models.

In essence, my question is: How should I proceed when the response variable ("distance" in this case) exhibits different distributions for two levels of an explanatory variable ("year" in this case)?